# How to fetch values by calling key from a text file to python

Tags: python-3.x

I have a text file Phone_book with text as:

```
{'sunny': ('123456', 'sunny@gmail.com')}.
```

I would like to fetch values by calling key(sunny) in python 3. X.

```
def search_contacts(self):
    key = input('Enter a name to search: ')
    with open('Phone_Book.txt','r') as Phone_book:
        print (Phone_book[key])
    else:
        print('not found')
```

Comment: Use the `json` module

Answer (score 0):

Use `json`

```
import json
dic={'sunny': ('123456', 'sunny@gmail.com')}
json_data = json.dumps(dic) #here json_data contains your dictionary in json format

#To write to a file
file = open('file.json','w')
file.write(json_data)
file.close()

#To read the data
file = open('file.json','r')
json_data = file.read()
file.close()
dic=json.loads(json_data)

##Now use the dic
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It was working well for single line but when I used this module to fetch data from a text file it was not able to fetch the data as a dictionary object. when I used to search for a key I am getting an TypeError as below. Plz help me with that.
"Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:/Users/L.sandeep reddy/PycharmProjects/assignments/test2.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(dict['sunny'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers"

Comment: If you have data stored in a text file, it will be read as a string only. You need to save your data as `json` first, and then use it to read the data. I know it is frustrating, but you have to do it like this